# Servlet request and validation

Tags: java, validation, jsp, servlets

I'd like to implement the following structure:

```
Servlet (GET) (put collection of X on request)
  |
JSP (output list of X) <--
  |                      |
Servlet (POST) ----------- Validation error!
  |
Validated OK, continue
```

I've implemented this using the pattern described in [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) but I want to know if there's a simple way of avoiding having to reload my collection of X during the validation stage since it's no longer on the request object. I am putting some validation messages on the request scope in the POST stage so I need to be able to access these.

I'm trying to avoid a framework at this stage since the scale of the project doesn't seem to justify it.

Comment: Frankly, using a framework is justified as long as it is not a "Hello world!" application.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to reload it during validation stage?

Answer (score 4):

Yes . The simplest way is to put the collection of X into the session .

Given a [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) , you can get its associated `HttpSession` by [getSession()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) . Then set the collection of X into the `HttpSession` by [setAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) , that is:

```
httpRequest.getSession().setAttribute("xxxxxxx" , collectionOfX)
```

Then , in the Servlet (POST) , you can get the collection of X from the `HttpSession` by

```
 httpRequest.getSession().getAttribute("xxxxxxx");
```

Comment: (Good practice is to remove the object from the session once you won't need it anymore, so you will not waste memory)

Comment: If it's not a problem to share the data among all browser tabs/windows and have them all influence on it, then it's okay to put it in session. But in this particular case it seems to be data which is supposed to be edited on a per-request basis. I would then not put it in session.

Comment: Although in this case I can actually put it on the session, I can foresee a situation where BalusC's point is valid (i.e. it is a request-specific attribute). In this case I assume I have no choice but to reload it in the "POST" so that it is available to the EL tags in the JSP.